# Recurring billing - magento 2

Tags: magento2, authorize.net, billing, recurring

I'm looking for an extension that allows Recurring Billing and that works with Authorize.Net's **Automated Recurring Billing (ARB)**. Meaning that subscriptions are send directly to authorize.net as recurring billing.

Right now all the extension we have tested send the subscriptions orders to authorize.net as new orders every time a billing occurs.

this might be an advantage over **ARB** as u can control everything from Magento, but still we would like to find an extension that sends subscription orders directly as **ARB**.

Comment: Check  link :  https://github.com/tegansnyder/Magento-Programmatically-Create-Recurring-Profiles-Authorize.net-CIM